# How to handle drives with a predefined speed profile in MoveIt 2?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, moveit, ros2-control, moveit2

Speed limits of the [MoveIt 2 packages](https://moveit.ros.org/) in `ros2` are normally defined in `kinematics.yaml`. In my case, a body is given which is actuated by a linear drive (see image). The real system has a known, but non-modifiable, velocity curve (accelerate, nominal velocity, decelerate). Thus, the control input $u$ can only be a signal ($1$), whereby the drive accelerates to nominal velocity, or it can be switched off ($0$), whereby the deceleration ramp is activated.

My question is whether this real hardware limitation can also be taken into account in the MoveIt 2 package.

Thank you very much!

[image: A real-life Velocity Profile of the linear moving object.]